# Why is my JavaScript apparently stuck in an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

I am defining an on 'submit' event as follows:

HTML code is:

```
<div class="messages">
            <ul>
                <li class="sent">
                    <img src="/img/person1.png" alt="" />
                    <p>How the hell am I supposed to get a jury to believe you when I am not even sure that I do?!</p>
                </li>
                <li class="replies">
                    <img src="/img/botimg.png" alt="" />
                    <p>When you're backed against the wall, break the god damn thing down.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="replies">
                    <img src="/img/botimg.png" alt="" />
                    <p>Excuses don't win championships.</p>
                </li>
                <li class="sent">
                    <img src="/img/person1.png" alt="" />
                    <p>Oh yeah, did Michael Jordan tell you that?</p>
                </li>
                <li class="replies">
                    <img src="/img/botimg.png" alt="" />
                    <p>No, I told him that.</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="message-input">
            <div class="wrap">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Write your message..." />
            <i class="fa fa-paperclip attachment" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <button class="submit"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Helper function:

```
function newMessage() {
    console.log("Inside newMessage");
    message = $(".message-input input").val();
    if($.trim(message) == '') {
        return false;
    }
    $('<li class="sent"><img src="/img/person1.png" alt="" /><p>' + message + '</p></li>').appendTo($('.messages ul'));
    $('.message-input input').val(null);
    $(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
};
```

Submit click function is:

```
$('.submit').click(function() {

  newMessage();

});
```

Now whenever I click the submit button, "Inside newMessage" message is continuously getting logged in the JavaScript console.

Comment: My best guess would be, becuase your `animate({})` is looping forever. That's the most common denominator in such issues

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Can you please create the working fiddle.

Comment: May be read up about the browser u are using and the support of animate function - caveats etc - I executed your code and I cannot replicate the endless looping. May be change it to window.scroll({top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

Comment: Your code is working for me with no errors.

Comment: It works when pressed entered. It stucks in infinite loop when submit button is pressed.

Comment: If you replace `console.log()` with `alert()` then you will see the same message is infinitely getting printed again and again.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/37gsfL8o/

Comment: Strange, my code works there in fiddle, but it gets stuck in Chrome. Any clues of this peculiar behavior?

Comment: That fiddle code is the complete code. I am just trying to create a dummy chatbot for practice. Not organization specific code.

Comment: That's not "minimal", that's a fuckton of code. It's not even separated into HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I didnot want to put the entire code and kept only the minimal code in this post. But some people wanted a fiddle working code.

Comment: Another observation I just have is the code works on chrome "incognito" mode but not in normal mode.

Comment: Since a cache clearing fixed this, I think the question can be closed. From the official close reasons: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @halfer I have also just voted to close this question. How stupid I was to open this question. Let's close it together. :)

Comment: Not stupid at all - often asking a question acts as a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I have loads of self-answered questions in my Stack Overflow history `:-)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is now working after clearing Chrome browsing history, particularly "cookies and other data".